# Consume the parameters of the method api c # put 2 (String, Object)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, webapi2

I am trying to consume an api of this type:

```
 api / food_order / {id}
```

the idea is from a console project.

I found this code:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri ("http: // localhost: 1565 /");
var response = client.PutAsJsonAsync ("api / food_order", p) .Result;
```

the detail is that it sends the object p but the idea is to send the object p
besides a string {id}

Comment: what is p? what does it look like?

Comment: _"I found this code"_ this is often where things go from bad to worse.

Comment: what is p ??? can you please explain your question more in detail to get perfect answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you are trying to consume an api : api/food_order/{id}

Try changing to:

```
var response = client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/food_order/{id}", p) .Result;
```

of if you are trying to pass the id as part of the body, try changing to:

```
var response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/food_order", new { Id = id, P = p }).Result;
```